# legendre's formula in number theory

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $(k!)^{(k-1)!}$ divides $(k!)!$ (k is a non-zero positive integer).  I Know Legendre's formula for counting p's power in $n!$ for any prime p,but here we have $(k!)!$ and can't establish a useful formula for that to help prove this problem.
I would be grateful for your helps.

Comment: I remember $ n! \cdot (n! - 1)! = (n!)!   $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\ n=(k-1)!\ $ then$$\frac{(k!)!}{(k!)^{(k-1)!}}=\frac{(nk)!}{(k!)^n}=\binom{nk}{k,k,k,\dots,k}=\binom kk\binom{2k}k\binom{3k}k\cdots\binom{nk}k$$which is of course an integer.

Comment: And that integer is divisible by $k!$.